# positioning layouts with multiple includes

Tags: android, layout

Why these :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/myCustomTitleBar"
        android:id="@+id/titlebar" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/myCustomToolBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_below="@id/titlebar" />

    <com.myname.myapp.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

is not working ?
The two `include`s are stacked / overlaying each other. (`layout_below` is not working)
Both `include`s -- `myCustomTitleBar` and `myCustomToolBar` -- are both `RelativeLayout`s.
Did I do something wrong ?

Desired outcome :

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your app sketch you shouldn't use `RelativeLayout` as root. `RelativeLayout` is exactly for overlaying items. You have to use `LinearLayout`. Of course each item of LinearLayout group must have appropriate `layout_width/layout_height` values.

**Root:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/relative_sample_a"/>

    <include layout="@layout/relative_sample_b"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#991022"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**relative_sample_a.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#AACC33">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="ButtonA"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="ButtonB"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**relative_sample_b.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#DDBB00">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="ButtonC"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to titlebar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include 
        layout="@layout/myCustomTitleBar"
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/myCustomToolBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_below="@id/titlebar" />

    <com.myname.myapp.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```